# LaTeX aligning different parts of the theorem

Tags: align

I'm using

```
 pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
```

How can I align parts a) and b) in a theorem like this:

```
a) For each a prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime 
   prime prime prime prime prime prime prime 
b) For each a prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime 
   prime prime prime prime prime prime prime
```

as I got only

```
   a) For each a prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime 
prime prime prime prime prime prime prime
   b) For each a prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime 
prime prime prime prime prime prime prime
```

I tried

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\linespread{1.6}
\begin{document}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\begin{lem}
\label{lemTwentyNineTwo}
Let $\lambda$ be the test sentence.

$(a)$ For each $a$ prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime

$(b)$ For each a prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime 
prime prime prime prime prime prime prime
\end{lem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `enumitem` package to define a custom enumerated-list environment, in which list items are "numbered" as `(a)`, `(b)`, etc rather than the usual `1.`, `2.`, etc.

The following MWE implements this idea.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{enumthm}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumthm]{label=(\alph*)}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm} Consider bla bla bla
\begin{enumthm}
\item For each a prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime
\item For each a prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime prime
\end{enumthm}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```